# Как заставить Mozilla Firefox  не терять cookie?

Tags: firefox

У меня регулярно слетают все Cookie. Только в Mozilla Firefox. В IE никаких проблем.

Можно было бы подумать, что это связано с устареванием, но почему-то обычно слетают сразу на всех сайтах. Очень похоже именно на глюк программы, а не на устаревание.

Данные автозаполнения не слетают.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки - приватность. Возможно, у вас не стоит галочка напротив кук.
Второй вариант - при очистке недавней истории стоит галочка "очистить куки".
И третий, наиболее вероятный. Если пользуетесь Ccleaner или подобной программой, проверьте, не очищает ли она куки ФФ.

Comment: Не помогло - сегодня опять всё слетело.<br>

1. Галочка стояла. На работе вроде бы всё нормально, там был просто выбран пресет "Будет запоминать историю". Сделал дома так же.<br>
2. Очистка недавней истории у меня вообще выключена. <br>
3. Никакими подобными программами не пользуюсь.